# watchkit2 : how to use siri with a specific language

Tags: xcode, swift2, watchkit, voice, siri

I am trying to use siri with japanese language but it is always take english language by default ..
please, any way to switch siri or any way to recognize voice in japanese language?

from apple documentation I found this function but I don't know how to use it, and there is no any example about it 
[presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestionsForLanguage](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestionsForLanguage:allowedInputMode:completion:)

I am using Xcode7 with swift2, watchkit2.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong function. That function exists to show suggestions for language on a text field.... but the language itself is defined on the settings. when you run that function, the suggestions for the text (in the language set on the Settings) is going to show, but the language you can only change by going to settings. I recommend you first change the watch language to japanese and then take it from there.

EDIT: As per iOS 10.0, you can just do the following:

If you're trying to do Speech Recognition, you can copy/paste the code below, and that will work. Not sure if you can do the same with auto-correction in text.

```
let code = "es_ES" // THIS WORKS FOR SPANISH, LOOKUP THE CODE FOR JAPANESE
    guard let speechMachine = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: code)) else{
        print("Error: Check if the code for the language selected is correct")
        return
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for answer, the watch and iPhone is already Japanese language, after many try it seems it depend on keyboard language, it must be Japanese language on iPhone at time using siri at watch ... and i don't have idea how to change input source to Japanese, every one saying : the user only can Decide that .

Comment: Install the japanese keyboard (on settings, add keyboard) - then select the japanese keyboard as your default. that will solve the problem

Comment: okay that woks but i need to change it programatically not manual, because every user have different settings